# Проблема с ярлыком запуска

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте.
Ничего не могу понять - помогите прояснить ситуацию.

Имеется:
Debian 8, amd64, Mate и приложение sqldeveloper.

Из консоли приложение запускается без ошибок:

```
everhide@station:~$ sh /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh 

 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
```

По ярлыку генерируемому автоматически нет - ничего не происходит.
Код ярлыка:

```
everhide@station:~/desktop$ cat Oracle-sqldeveloper.desktop 
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=SQL Developer
Comment=Oracle SQL Developer
Icon=/opt/sqldeveloper/icon.png
Exec=sqldeveloper
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
Categories=X-Red-Hat-Extra;Application;Development;
```

Остальные ярлыки полностью работоспособны.
Я так понимаю, возможный корень проблемы кроется в том, что приложение изначально разрабатывалось для систем RedHat\CentOS\Fedora и было установлено мною c помощью alien. Тем не менее... Подскажите, куда копать? На что смотреть? Буду благодарен за советы.

Comment: В ярлыке вроде сказано выполнять просто sqldeveloper без расширения и я плюс к этому сомневаюсь, что /opt/sqldeveloper в PATH, вы туда попробуйте целиком путь прописать. /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh

Comment: Файл по пути "/usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper" содержит конструкцию "/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh" - и она работает и запускается.

Comment: @everhide, а просто `sqldeveloper` в консоли пробовали запускать? М.б. этот файл неисполяемый?

Comment: Команда в консоли "sqldeveloper" как раз вызовет файл "/usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper", которая исполнит скрипт "sh /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh". Мне же хочется работающий ярлык, чтобы не держат лишнюю консоль открытой лишь для запуска sh скрипта.

Comment: @everhide, del, ответ на мое уточнение уже есть.

Answer (score 3):

вместо:

```
Exec=sqldeveloper
```

можно указать команду, которую надо вызывать:

```
Exec=sh /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
```

---

если при «запуске» ярлыка нет никакой реакции, посмотрите, какие строки при этом добавляются в файл `~/.xsession-errors`.

---

в качестве гипотезы: возможно, этому скрипту (или какой-нибудь из программ, вызываемых внутри скрипта) требуется полноценный *tty*, который, естественно, не создаётся при «запуске» ярлыка.

для таких случаев и предназначен параметр `terminal=true`, при наличии которого запускается эмулятор терминала, которому уже и передаётся для выполнения команда, указанная в параметре `exec=...`.

Comment: Пробовал такие варианты. И с кавычками в пути и без. И без xdg-open напрямую через /usr/bin/bash и с текущим вариантом - не запускается. =\

Comment: дополнил ответ. если не знаете, что означают строки, который добавятся в лог, добавьте их в текст вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Поставил флаг отображения консоли в True. Открылась консоль, которая указала на конфигурационный файл данного приложения, выкинув ошибку о том, что JDK не указан. После указания JDK - файл запустился. Поставил Terminal=True - все работает как надо. Еще раз СПАСИБО!